# Is there any order exists in unordered_set in c++?

Tags: c++, hash, stl, unordered-set

```
int main(){
    unordered_set<int> S;
    S.insert(1);
    S.insert(10);
    S.insert(100);
    S.insert(64);

    for(auto &x: S){
        cout<<x<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    S.erase(S.find(1),S.end());
    for(auto &x: S){
        cout<<x<<" ";
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
64 1 100 10 
64
```

This is same for every IDE and for every time.
Isn't `unordered_set` uses hash?
And hash don't have an order.

Comment: IDE has nothing to it. This is behavior is result of implementation of standard library delivered with compiler. For example you will see different results for clang and msvc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed it's a poor name. I believe the C++ standards committee wanted to call it `std::hash_set` but there were too many so-called `std::hash_set`s in circulation prior to standardisation in C++11. The same applies to `std::unordered_map`: see the `hash_map` of the Boost distribution targeting C++03 and earlier.

They are indeed ordered insofar that hashing buckets are ordered, but the main point one needs to make is that you're not supposed to *care* about the order.

(Fortunately in C++17 `boost::optional` grew into `std::optional`: hopefully lessons were learnt, and something like `std::discretionary` avoided.)

Answer (score 2):

> This is same for every IDE and for every time.

Not promising anything about the order of elements is not the same as promising a different order every time.

> And hash don't have an order.

There are elements, and they can be iterated. That's *an* order. They aren't in a *natural* order.

Answer (score 1):

Hash is deterministic, so unordered_set is deterministic, else you would not be able to retrieve the elements in the set.

The order you see is simply the content of the buckets in the unordered_set, the order can change if the unordered_set decide to resize.